# CSS font-family for label not working

Tags: css, label, font-family

i have the below simple code

test content

and

css code

label{
font-family: "Andale Mono"

}

whatever font we added font style is not changing for the label content , any suggestion please.

Comment: Need more context, but try adding label { font-family: 'Andale Mono' !important }

Comment: Can you show us the HTML file aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Try?

```
<font face="Andale Mono" color="Black">
```

Also did you include a link to Andale Mono in the  tag?

Comment: O my. The `font` element is seriously out of date. Please don't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Use it or try to apply using ID/CLASS

```
label
{
font-family:"Andale Mono",Georgia,Serif;
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I find that, Andale Mono is not a google font. So, in that case, you have to manually add the font to your project using @font-face. See this for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp .

And another thing.. for changing the font for a label element, you have to follow the main syntax of font-family.
Suppose:

```
label {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  // A google font
}
```

Here, 'Roboto' is A font family name and 'sans-serif' is a generic family name. You have to put both, a family name and a generic family name.
It worked for me.